# jQuery version compatibility problem with accordion menu

Tags: jquery, version, compatibility

I'm testing [this accordion](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-accordion/?bcsi_scan_EE24D69099E67A3A=Q7LcBTp3jmXmJQ4Wkaa+tQsAAAAvbXc9):

It comes with an old version of jQuery. Works fine, but when a try to upgrade to a newer version of jQuery which I need for other functionality it stops working.

What can I do?

Answer (score 4):

Use the [jQuery UI Accordian](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/). The author of the original plugin, Jörn Zaefferer is also involved in the UI project and they ported most of the features.

It states on his original plugin page

> This plugin is now part of jQuery UI
>   and this standalone version won’t be
>   updated anymore. The page will remain
>   as a reference.